# New PayPal IPN simulator lacks country codes and currencies

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

Our IPN handler uses GBP in the mc_currency field (which has been working fine for years) but it looks like the IPN simulator on the new PayPal developer site only works with USD. If you select Transaction type = Web Accept then the fields address_country, address_country_code and mc_currency only have options for the US.
I've had no response to my PayPal support ticket on this issue. Surely it must be affecting thousands of non-US developers.

Comment: Still not fixed. Since this is a basic feature and it doesn't seem to be impacting many other users, it makes me think that PayPal is no-longer a widely-used system for online payments. Maybe it's time to look at other providers.

Answer (score 2):

It's possible to work around this issue by altering the HTML request sent back to PayPal.

In order to make an IPN request using GBP I just used firebug to change the value="USD" to value="GBP" of the mc_currency selector and then submitted the form and GBP was sent to my handler URL.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have your PayPal support ticket number?  I can file a Feature Request/Improvement.  However, in the meantime the only way to get the values sent back to your IPN script with different values for these variables would be to walk through the actual checkout flow.

Comment: Thanks. The ticket is 130425-000222. This is not a feature request it is a mission-critical bug report. The old IPN simulator did not have this bug.